# Dependência do Facebook para autenticação

Tags: facebook, login

Em muitos casos, stackoverflow pt sendo um deles, faço login com o Facebook. Sopunhamos agora que deixo de querer fazer parte do Facebook e apago minha conta do Facebook. O que acontece com a minha conta nos sites em que dependia do login com Facebook?

Por exemplo neste, no stackoverflow pt:

**Perco também a minha conta?**

**Existe alguma forma de integrar a minha conta autenticada pelo facebook com uma nova que terei de fazer?**

**O Login com o facebook continua a funcionar? Ou seja, deixo de ter facebook mas os meus dados continuam lá para contornar casos como este?**

Nunca experiencei nem ouvi/li nada sobre esta eventualidade, gostava de saber como isto é solucionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que sim, que perdes, pois quando fazes login com a conta de facebook, ele usa um SDK para o realizar.

A sessão PHP é uma sessão própria do Facebook, portanto sim, deixarás de ter acesso. Porém há certos sites que pegam na informação e inserem na Base de Dados deles.

Documentação muito boa sobre o uso do SDK:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Documentação sobre como guardar os dados do Facebook na própria Base de Dados

- http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/

> **Nota:** Peço desculpa colocar links externos, mas é muita documentação para transpor e penso que sejam bastante úteis.

Comment: Mas isso será bom? Estarmos assim tão dependentes do Facebook? Sendo assim, se perdermos as nossas outras contas vou começar a pensar duas vezes antes de fazer de fazer login com o facebook

Comment: Acata benefícios e malefícios, por um lado consegues ter uma maior centralidade de informação e num só clique consegues configurar todos os campos, e-mail, fotografia, pass, username, informações adicionais, etc... 
Por outro lado, perdes o acesso à conta e adeus...

Comment: Acata benefícios e malefícios, por um lado consegues ter uma maior centralidade de informação e num só clique consegues configurar todos os campos, e-mail, fotografia, pass, username, informações adicionais, etc... 
Por outro lado, perdes o acesso à conta e adeus...